# "Неотвеченные вопросы без ответов" в заголовке

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, локализация, неотвеченные-вопросы

Фильтруем вопросы по любому тегу, кликаем на вкладку "Без ответа". В заголовке закладки браузера (то, что определяется тегом `title` обычно) появляется "Неотвеченные вопросы без ответов". Выглядит не очень, примерно как "масло масляное".

Comment: Так и в английской версии так: "Unanswered Questions with No Answers". Может быть у Вас есть более подходящий вариант перевода?

Comment: Значит, и в английской версии "масло масляное". Хотя там я не знаю, может, в английском это нормально звучит? В любом случае, просто "Неотвеченные вопросы" или "Вопросы без ответов" звучит более естественно, чем то, что сейчас есть.

Comment: дело в том, что в понятие "Unanswered questions" на сайтах SE входит несколько больше, чем это ожидается от обычного языка. Отсюда и такие фразы, которые кажутся несколько странными.

Comment: А что туда еще входит, кроме вопросов, нак которые никто не ответил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сайтах сети Stack Exchange под фразой "Неотвеченные вопросы" (в оригинале "Unanswered Questions") понимаются вопросы, для которых либо нет ответов вовсе (удалённые ответы, понятно дело, не учитываются), либо есть только такие ответы, рейтинг которых не превышает 0 и ни один из ответов не принят автором в качестве верного (т.е. отсутствует зелёная галочка).

Если вы откроете вкладку "новые" для вопросов по какой-либо метке, то увидите описание справа вида:

> N вопросов без положительных и принятых ответов

Таким образом "Неотвеченные вопросы без ответов" это всего лишь подмножество упомянутых выше вопросов. Это подмножество содержит только те вопросы, где кол-во ответов равно нулю (или все ответы удалены).

Понимая это, фраза уже не кажется такой странной, как изначально. И с точки зрения сайта это поведение "by-design".

Comment: Так намного понятнее, спасибо. Пока не приходит ничего в голову, как эти названия можно было бы получше сформулировать.

Comment: А мне из соседнего ответа вариант нравится.

Comment: @Qwertiy а лицензия на утверждение переводов у меня.

Answer (score 3):

Предложение:

### Заменить "Неотвеченные" на "Нерешённые".

Ведь то, что на вопрос ответили, ещё не означает, что он решён.

Comment: Да, неплохой вариант. Посмотрим, что ответственные лица скажут.

Comment: "Решённый" это вроде как только ТС решает галочкой. Посему не очень подходящий вариант, имхо. Либо надо вводить своё определение для того, что есть "Решённый" и тоже на него ссылаться. А это значит, опять будут сомнения, как это вопрос без галочки, но является решённым.