# Можно ли ставить ассоциацию, если вопрос не является переводом?

Tags: поддержка, ассоциация-вопросов, самоответы

Я достаточно часто перевожу вопросы с en so, вот какой вопрос возник при переводе.

Можно ли ставить ассоциацию, если вопрос не является точным переводом?

Я написал самоответ взяв свой код. (Что-то мне показалось, что так нагляднее будет, чем код из оригинального вопроса) Ну и остальной текст соответственно тоже не было смысла переносить, написал свой.

Ссылка на вдохновивший пост в ответе есть, а ассоциации разумеется нет, хотя посты очень близкие, на одну тему.

Поэтому у меня возникают вопросы:

- Насколько точным должен быть перевод, чтобы можно было проставлять ассоциацию?
- Вообще, инструмент ассоциации предназначен только для переводов?
- Если только для переводов, то может имеет смысл сделать какой-то механизм для ассоциаций, которые не являются точными переводами?

Updated @Grundy предложил [дубликат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5315/213987) и там есть здравая мысль: предлагается ставить ассоциацию в случае:

> Объединять стоит только те вопросы, которые, будь они на одном языке,
>   вы бы закрыли как дубликаты. Решение, как и всегда, принимает
>   сообщество большинством голосов.

Однако мне не совсем понятно, как можно решать вопрос "проставить ассоциацию или нет решается большинством голосов". Я просто могу проставить ассоциацию (добавив комментарий) и никакого голосования не будет. Через какое-то время Николас запустит скрипт и при этом тоже никакого голосования не будет.

Вероятно, стоит уточнить этот момент подробнее.

Comment: Если кому нужен конкретный пример: [пост на en so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43210508/5752652), [мой пост на ru so](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/981592/213987)

Comment: можно конечно и про это был вопрос как мне кажется

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какие вопросы можно и стоит ассоциировать?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5315/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: _Объединять стоит только те вопросы, которые, будь они на одном языке, вы бы закрыли как дубликаты_

Comment: @Grundy Имху, не совсем дубликат. Вот это мне непонятно: "решение по ассоциациям принимает сообщество большинством голосов". (А в целом ссылка на мой взгляд полезна, не было бы этого предложения про голосование - можно было бы закрыть как дубль) Вот например, я добавил-таки ссылку, как за неё голосовать? Не ставить ассоциации, пока не наберётся 5 upvote'ов на комментарии? Или флагать, а там пусть модераторы решают?

Comment: Да, вполне можно флагать и удалить комментарий. Обычно за/против ассоциаций не голосуют. Поэтому достаточно только той части сообщения, что я привел выше в комментарии.

Answer (score 7):

Как уже указали в комментариях (и продублировали в самом вопросе), ассоциации - это некий особенный механизм межсайтовых дубликатов. Работает он, по сути, в тестовом режиме, поэтому проводить дальнейшие параллели с обычными (внутрисайтовыми) дубликатами, как, например, возможность голосовать за "дубликатизм", и необязательность наличия ответов, всё же не стоит.

Учитывая, что [плашка на другом сайте сообщает о наличии ответа](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311016/339911) на ruSO, минимальное и достаточное требование для ассоциирования вопросов такое:

- Будь они заданы на одном сайте, их стоило бы объективно закрыть как дубликаты;
- На ruSO имеется ответ (не обязательно такой же по сути, как на другом сайте, но, как мне кажется, явно с положительным рейтингом, т.е. чтобы исключить ["неотвеченные"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6560/176217) (unanswered) вопросы).

Проекция именно по (дословному) переводу возникает, скорее всего, по причине того, что это наиболее очевидный способ создания межсайтовых дубликатов (ассоциаций), но не единственный. Например, вопросы могут зародиться совершенно независимо на португальском и русском SO, а в некоторый момент, кто-то (интересно кто бы это мог быть) сможет в них распознать дубликаты и предложить ассоциацию.

Comment: "Межсайтовые дубликаты", неплохо звучит.

Comment: @AK можно даже попробовать пропеть. Вы, кажется, умеете это :)

Answer (score 4):

Как по мне, если выполняются два условия, то можно:

1. Ответ решает проблему.
2. Подход для решения проблемы тот же самый, что и в оригинале.

А то, что вы используете свой код, даже лучше (:

Comment: Да, @Grundy уже нашёл тему, где предлагалось подобное решение. Я там вычитал про "голосование", можете добавить в ответ мнение по этому подвопросу?

Comment: Ассоциация ставится для **вопросов**, поэтому пункт 2 не совсем подходит. Если я правильно понимаю задумку механизма ассоциаций, то это по сути некий особенный режим межсайтовых дубликатов.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ  Вы совершенно верно понимаете механизм ассоциаций.